# Which table in TFS db has Team Name data of TFS?

Tags: tfs

We are working on TFS databases (TFS_Warehouse, TFS_FabrikamFibreCollection) to create some report related to TFS activities. We need to generate reports based on Team Name.
TFS maintained
following hierarchies for projects: 
ProjectCollection
Project
Team

We are able to map ProjectCollections and Projects in the TFS_Warehouse database, they are in DimTeamProject. 
But ee are not able to map Team Name in TFS_Warehouse / TFS_FabrikamFibreCollection database. 
If you have any idea about Team Name mappings with DB tables please let me know.

Comment: You **should not** report against the TFS operational stores. The only supported option for reporting is the `Tfs_Warehouse` database and the Analysis cube.

Comment: Yeah, I am retrieving all data from TFS_WareHouse only. But I am not able to find team name data point in TFS_WareHouse. Can you suggest where I can get that?

Comment: Same question, did you ever find anything?

Comment: No, I used TFS Web API to find the team Names

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest solution I found for your question:

```
SELECT map.[TeamId]
      ,map.[ProjectId]
      ,proj.[ProjectNodeName] AS [Team Project Name]
      ,ado.[SamAccountName] AS [Team Name]
  FROM [Tfs_FabrikamFibreCollection].[dbo].[tbl_TempTeamProjectMapping] map
  JOIN [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimTeamProject] proj ON map.[ProjectId] = proj.[ProjectNodeGUID]
  JOIN [Tfs_FabrikamFibreCollection].[dbo].[ADObjects] ado ON map.[TeamId] = ado.[TeamFoundationId]
```

For some reason, the `[tbl_TempTeamProjectMapping]` table includes the default security groups (Readers, Contributors, Project Administrators, etc.) but these can easily be filtered out of the results.

Answer (score 0):

We don't suggest handle database directly. You can create Excel reports instead. Usually, when we create a Team, we'll create an area path with the name of the team. So you can try to select Area Path in the field:

[image]

Comment: Also, you can check Area Path in table [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimArea].

Comment: Area path and Team Name and separate data points. A team can have more than associate Area Path as per my understanding. Even Area Path may have different name than Team Name. So I can't use Area Path as Team Name

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend staying away from the SQL and use the TFS API. The following PowerShell invokes the TFS client namespace and brings back the collections and projects.

```
#region Get-TfsSummary 
function Get-TfsSummary{
param(
    [parameter(Position=0,HelpMessage='    Full server name. e.g. tfsServer.domain.net',Mandatory)]
    [string]
    $serverFQDN, # eg 'tfsServer.domain.net'

    [parameter(Position=1,HelpMessage='    port used to access the TFS server e.g. 8080')]
    [string]
    $serverPort, # eg '8080'

    [parameter(Position=2,HelpMessage='    The root virtual directory for TFS. Default is tfs e.g. tfs ')]
    [string]
    $tfsRootNode # eg 'tfs'
)
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
$tfsUri = 'http://' + $serverFQDN + ':' + $serverPort +'/' + $tfsRootNode + '/'
$tfsConfigurationServer = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory]::GetConfigurationServer($tfsUri)
$tpcService = $tfsConfigurationServer.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamProjectCollectionService")
$sortedCollections = $tpcService.GetCollections() | Sort-Object -Property Name
$numberOfProjects = 0
$numberOfStoppedCollections = 0
$numberOfStartedProjects = 0
$numberOfStoppedProjects = 0
$isStopped = ''

foreach($collection in $sortedCollections) {
  $collectionUri = $tfsUri + "/" + $collection.Name
  $tfsTeamProject = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($collectionUri)

  try {
    $cssService = $tfsTeamProject.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.ICommonStructureService4")

  }catch{}
    $sortedProjects = $cssService.ListProjects() | Sort-Object -Property Name

  if($collection.State -eq 'Stopped'){
    $isStopped = ' but is stopped'
    $numberOfStoppedCollections++
    $numberOfStoppedProjects += $sortedProjects.Count
  }


  Write-Host "`n" $collection.Name "(" $collection.Id ")- contains" $sortedProjects.Count "project(s)$isStopped"
  $isStopped = ''

  foreach($project in $sortedProjects)
  {
    $numberOfProjects++
    Write-Host (" - " + $project.Name + " (" + $project.Uri +  ")")
  }

}

$numberOfStartedProjects =  $numberOfProjects - $numberOfStoppedProjects
Write-Host
Write-Host "Number of stopped collections          " $numberOfStoppedCollections
Write-Host "Total number of project collections    " $sortedCollections.Count
Write-Host "Online projects                        " $numberOfStartedProjects
Write-Host "Total number of projects               " $numberOfProjects
}
#endregion Get-TfsSummary
```